# Adding a List Within a List

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

For some reason, we were asked to use a stored procedure and call this stored procedure using Entity Framework. Here is the sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE SampleStoredProcedure () AS 
    SELECT TOP 10 SiteId, SiteName, DayOfTheWeek, OpenTime, CloseTime
    FROM Sites s, BusinessHours b
    WHERE s.SiteId = b.SiteId
    Group By SiteId, SiteName, DayOfTheWeek, OpenTime, CloseTime
```

These sites have business hours on another table with the following SAMPLE schema, wheren one site can have 5 entries for business hours corresponding to Monday to Friday operations.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusinessHours](
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [SiteId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [DayOfTheWeek] [int] NOT NULL,
   [OpenTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
   [CloseTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
```

The thing is, the database was poorly designed, so Sites.SiteId is not the primary key and you cannot reference it as a FK for BusinessHours.SiteId.

Now, on the server, I want to have an object that maps like this:

```
IEnumerable<SampleStoredProcedure_Result> test = dbContext.SampleStoredProcedure
```

I want to map this SampleStoredProcedure_Result to something like:

```
Class Result {
    public int SiteId {get; set;}
    public int SiteName {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<BusinessHours> BusinessHours { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure how can I efficiently code this aside from brute force approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to map this SampleStoredProcedure_Result to something like:
>
> ```
> class Result {
>     public int SiteId {get; set;}
>     public int SiteName {get; set;}
>     IEnumerable<BusinessHours> BusinessHours { get; set; } }      
> }
> ```

Here's how you can map a collection of `SampleStorecProcedure_Result` objects to a collection of `Result` objects:

```
IEnumerable<Result> results = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.SiteId, x.SiteName })
                                  .Select(g => new Result
                                  {
                                      SiteId = g.Key.SiteId,
                                      SiteName = g.Key.SiteName,
                                      BusinessHours = g.Select(x => new BusinessHours
                                      {
                                         DayOfTheWeek = x.DayOfTheWeek,
                                         OpenTime = x.OpenTime,
                                         CloseTime = x.CloseTime
                                      })
                                  });
```